# clear cookies while logout in spring security or in angular

Tags: angularjs, spring, cookies, spring-security

My trial code to remove cookies

```
.logout()
.logoutUrl("/access/logout")
.logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler() {
 @Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(
HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response,
Authentication a) throws IOException, ServletException {
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
  }
})
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
.invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

This code is of logout security with `HttpSecurity`.

Here I am getting issue to delete cookies
in `logoutSuccessHandler` in logger it shows cookies = 1 and i.e `JESSESIONID`
So my problem is how to delete cookie at the time of logout
or if is there any another way or any way in angular then please tell me

Comment: Invalidating the http session is enough. The JSESSION_ID is not valid anymore after this. I you really want to remove it anyway you might want to use the $cookies angular service on the client side, but only after the session is cancelled on the server side

Comment: ok then if i want to clear it on angularJs side then how should I do that

Comment: Post the ng code involved in logout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through many blogs on spring security I got answer,

`.invalidateHttpSession(true)` :- it is used to clear our session
and
`.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")` :- it is used to delete cookies

use this after your success handler so that it will remove all cookies after logout

**EDIT**

And if any one want to handle cookies from frontend side then you can handle it using `ng-cookies` in AngularJs.